# Change the text in a div when hovered over a list element

Tags: html, css, hover, division, auto-update

So I have a list set up so that when I hover over the different elements it will change the picture to the right of the elements. I want text to go along with the picture so I would like that in a div below. Is there a way with css to make it so when I hover over an element in the list it will change the text in the div? Normally I try and figure these things out myself but I have been searching for a while and can't seem to find a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="relative">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Arms</a>
        <img src="img/arms.jpg" alt="">

          <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 1</div>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Back</a>
        <img src="img/back.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Head</a>
        <img src="img/head.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Feet</a>
        <img src="img/feet.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Legs</a>
        <img src="img/legs.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Chair</a>
        <img src="img/chair.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Desk</a>
        <img src="img/desk.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here is the relative css:

```
ul {
    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-position:right top;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
li {
    font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;
    height: 100px;
}
a {
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 99px;    
}
a:hover {
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
}
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 700;
    height: 900;
}

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
h3{
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:500px;
}
img {
    display: none;
    height: 700;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 600px;
    background-color:red;
}
a:hover + img,
img:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a style to show and hide the text div, like you already do for the img:

```
a + img + div
{
  display: none;
}
a:hover + img + div
{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Use the `li:hover` event to hide and show the corrsponding `div`.

```css
ul {
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: right top;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
}
a {
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 99px;
}
a:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 700;
  height: 900;
}
div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 500px;
}
img {
  display: none;
  height: 700;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}
a:hover + img,
img:hover {
  display: block;
}
.absolute {
  display: none;
}
.relative li:hover div.absolute {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Arms</a>
      <img src="img/arms.jpg" alt="">

      <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 1</div>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Back</a>
      <img src="img/back.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Head</a>
      <img src="img/head.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feet</a>
      <img src="img/feet.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Legs</a>
      <img src="img/legs.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Chair</a>
      <img src="img/chair.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Desk</a>
      <img src="img/desk.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a .wrapper div, but you have more possibilities, when you are using javascript.

```css
ul {
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position:right top;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0;
}
li {
  font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
}
a {
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 99px;    
}
a:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 700;
  height: 900;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
h3{
  margin-left:200px;
  margin-top:500px;
}
img {
  height: 700;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 101px;
  background-color:red;
  width: 600px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Arms</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/309/?random" alt="">
        <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 1</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Back</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/308/?random" alt="">
        <div class="absolute">TEXT TEST 2</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Head</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/306/?random" alt="">

      </div></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Feet</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/305/?random" alt="">

      </div></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Legs</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/304/?random" alt="">

      </div></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Chair</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/301/?random" alt="">
        </div>
        </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Desk</a>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/302/?random" alt="">

      </div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with javascript and jQuery. But I'm not sure if it solves your issue.

Just add an eventlistener to all `li` that changes the text of the corresponding div.

```
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        $("#TEXT1").text($(this).children("a").text());
    })
```

You can give a tag to all your `li` if you have some you don't want to act this way.